# SAAB 93 Car Audio system upgrade

Tags: audio, saab

I have a 2009 Vector trim Sports Saloon version. With that trim basically you get a Radio/CD audio system with ability to play mp3 CD's. However it's time to move on for some better solutions with USB and Bluetooth supports, as burning all those CDs is messy stuff.

What I want is to have ablity to control the music from my steering wheel and play music from USB drive/ Android Phone / iPod.

I know that there are USB emulators out there on the market, but had no luck in finding one for my particullar model.

Has anybody something available on the market?

Comment: This seems to be looking for for shopping assistance than you having an actual issue, thus the close vote.

Comment: @Paulster2 if you have a suggestion what device could be used, or maybe you've got an idea of how to install an OEM solution as better trim SAAB's came with a full audio package including the GPS navigation solution.

Comment: You may get a better response if you were to ask this over in the chat room called [*The Pitstop*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop). We can free form a little easier over there.